# Computing the Cohomology of a genus-2 surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I know that it has already been discussed which is the Cohomology of a genus-2 surface but I have a very concrete question about the procedure.

I want to compute the Cohomology of the following genus-2 surface using Mayer-Vietoris:[image]

If I write the Mayer-Vietoris sequence (where $H^j(X;k_{X})=:H^j(X)$), assuming $k$ is a field, I get:
\begin{align}
0\rightarrow H^0(T)\rightarrow H^0(X)\oplus H^0(Y)\rightarrow H^0(S)\rightarrow H^1(T)\rightarrow H^1(X)\oplus H^1(Y)\rightarrow H^1(S)\rightarrow H^2(T)\rightarrow ...
\end{align}
Since $T$ is connected and knowing the cohomology of $X,Y,S$ I get:
\begin{align}
0\rightarrow k\rightarrow k \oplus k\rightarrow k \rightarrow H^1(T)\rightarrow k^4\oplus 0\rightarrow k\rightarrow H^2(T)\rightarrow 0
\end{align}

But now I don't know how to conclude that $H^1(T)=k^4$ and $H^2(T)=k$.

I believe that it follows from knowing how the map $H^1(X)\oplus H^1(Y)\rightarrow H^1(S)$ works, but I am not able to understand this map.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The map you need to understand comes from the inclusions of $S$ in $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Try visualizing what happens when you "slide $S$ to the left/right" in $X$,$Y$ respectively. What does this tell you about this map homotopically?

Comment: If you "slide S to the right" it vanishes. While to the left, I am not sure, does it also vanish?

Comment: Yes, it's just like sliding a rubber band off a bottle.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It might be easier to see the map $S \hookrightarrow X \xrightarrow{\sim} \bigvee_4 \mathbb{S}^1$ on $H_1(- ; k)$, i.e. what happens to the boundary circle of $X$ in the retraction to the wedge of four circles. Then the map on $H^1$ is the dual or transpose.